# SEO Effects on sharing one nameserver for multiple websites on shared ips

Tags: seo, nameserver, website-promotion

We have a dedicated server and 5 shared IPs, and we are running around 20 websites on each shared IP. Our websites nature of business is same but each website belong to different country, For e.g., we have SEO services in Australia has different website, and web design services in Australia has different website and so on for other countries.

All I want to know that we have only one nameserver on our dedicated server and whenever I search on Google SEO services in Australia, my ranking on this keyword shows on page 4 or page 3 or page 2, my other website(web design in Australia) is also ranking on that page somewhere near around my SEO website.

And, that is happening with all of my websites. Can anybody help me out why this is happening with my websites? and what should I do to sort out this thing?

Answer (score 1):

Google specifically allows you to run separate sites that geographically target each country. As such, it doesn't really matter if they are all using the same nameservers.  You are not violating any policies that you need to hide from Google.

If possible, you should host each site in or near the country it is targeting.  This isn't a strict requirement, but hosting in the country is best for user experience and it gives Google a strong signal as to the audience that you are trying to target.

You need to make sure that each site is running on a domain name that is appropriate for the country you are targeting.  You should either have a top level domain for that country, or use one from [Google's list of generic top level domains](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/1347922?hl=en).

You should also register each of the sites in Google Webmaster Tools.  If a site is not on a top level domain for that country that is automatically geotargeted by Google, you need to [use Webmaster Tools to set the geographic targeting](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/62399?hl=en).

Answer (score 0):

It's always better to assign 2 or more name servers to web sites with different IP addresses, but if your server is down websites wont work. Better you ask a log report with your server team to check uptime of your server and server response time for user queries. If this is okay there is nothing wrong with name servers. I suggest you to optimize your web site for your target audience by specify it with Google Webmaster Tools. Create separate subdomain for target countries and deliver content according to it.